# Projecting vectors onto line (finding matrix associated with transformation)

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, matrices, geometry, linear-transformations

Find the matrix associated with the transformation that projects vectors in $\mathbb{R^3}$ orthogonally onto the line with parametric equations x=t, y=0, z=t. Find using rotations and projections. [image]

Thoughts:
I know that the direction vector of the line given is $<1,0,1>$.  I want to project vectors in $\mathbb{R^3}$ orthogonally onto this line.  I know there is some formula where you just plug in different vectors and get the final matrix.  However, I do not want do not want to get the answer like this, although I know it can be done.

I want to do this by rotations.  I was thinking that I have to first multiply by a rotation matrix (rotating vectors), then project onto the XY plane (and multiply by this matrix), and then multiply by the transpose of the first rotation matrix to rotate back.  The product of these matrices I was thinking should give the matrix associated with the transformation that projects vectors orthogonally onto the line.
However, I'm not sure if this is entirely the correct process and what exactly the first rotation matrix should be for the first one (that is, by what degrees and in which direction).

Any help would be much appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Since you’re supposed to project onto a *line*, try finding a rotation that maps this line onto one of the coordinate axes.

Comment: I'm thinking I should project onto the x axis, but how would I do this?

Comment: The line is in the $x$-$z$ plane. Seems like it shouldn’t be too hard for you to find an appropriate rotation.

Comment: Yes, I know it is the x z plane, but which axis should i map this line onto?

Comment: It doesn’t matter. Pick one.

Comment: Ok got it, I figured it out.

Comment: Good! You should post your solution as an answer once MSE lets you.